# is there a freeware form creator with import csv capabilities?

Tags: data-visualization, forms, csv, data-transfer

I have a sensor that outputs (csv format) logged data like date, time, temperature, pressure, etc)

Can anyone recommend  a free form creator that I could design graphically the fields I need to be displayed and then import a csv file in this form with all the data it has logged and it would fill automatically each field?

Thanks!